# prototypical inheritance, new vs prototype?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between using the 'new' key word in a constructor's prototype property to create inheritance and the Object.create? Is one better then other?

```
function Employee(){
     this.pay=500;
  }

function Manager(){
     this.reports=[1,2,3,4];
 }
 Manager.prototype=Object.Create(Employee.prototype);
 Manager.pay+=100;

// or the using new to construct a new object

function Manager(){
     this.reports=[1,2,3,4];
 }
 Manager.prototype= new Employee();
 Manager.pay+=100;
```

Comment: In both cases, `Manager.pay` is `NaN`

Comment: Yes, `Object.create` is better. See the duplicate.